# How to fix metadata is not set for resolving open graph and twitter in next js project

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, next.js13, next-auth

I encountered an error when running the build version in Next.js. Despite adding meta tags to the layout, the issue persists. As a Next.js newcomer, I seek guidance on resolving this issue. Any assistance or advice to troubleshoot and rectify the error would be greatly appreciated.

```
⚠ metadata.metadataBase is not set for resolving social open graph or twitter images, using "http://localhost:3000". See https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/generate-metadata#metadatabase
Error: There is a problem with the server configuration. Check the server logs for more information.
    at getServerSession (D:\isomorphic\.next\server\chunks\2443.js:30:19947)
    at async RootLayout (D:\isomorphic\.next\server\chunks\9212.js:1:20494)
[Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] {
  digest: '2927497250'
}
```

My layout file in app/layout.tsx

```
// RootLayout.js
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth/next';
import { authOptions } from '@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/auth-options';
import AuthProvider from '@/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/auth-provider';
import GlobalDrawer from '@/app/shared/drawer-views/container';
import GlobalModal from '@/app/shared/modal-views/container';
import { ThemeProvider } from '@/app/shared/theme-provider';
import { siteConfig } from '@/config/site.config';
import { inter, lexendDeca } from '@/app/fonts';
import cn from '@/utils/class-names';

const NextProgress = dynamic(() => import('@/components/next-progress'), {
  ssr: false,
});
// styles
import '@/app/globals.css';

const defaultMetadata = {
  description: 'This is the description',
  openGraph: {
    title: 'Title website',
    description: 'This is the description',
    image: 'url/image.png',
  },
  twitter: {
    card: 'summary_large_image',
    site: '@eMartiiin94',
    title: 'Title website',
    description: 'This is the description',
    image: 'url/image.png',
  },
};

export const metadata = {
  title: siteConfig.title,
  ...defaultMetadata,
};

export default async function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  const session = await getServerSession(authOptions);
  return (
    <html
      lang="en"
      dir="ltr"
      // required this one for next-themes, remove it if you are not using next-theme
      suppressHydrationWarning
    >
      {/* Remove the Head component */}
      <body
        // to prevent any warning that is caused by third-party extensions like Grammarly
        suppressHydrationWarning
        className={cn(inter.variable, lexendDeca.variable, 'font-inter')}
      >
        {/* Add metadata directly using the Metadata API */}
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>{metadata.title}</title>
        <meta name="description" content={metadata.description} />
        
        {/* OpenGraph Meta Tags */}
        <meta property="og:title" content={metadata.openGraph.title} />
        <meta property="og:description" content={metadata.openGraph.description} />
        <meta property="og:image" content={metadata.openGraph.image} />
        
        {/* Twitter Meta Tags */}
        <meta name="twitter:card" content={metadata.twitter.card} />
        <meta name="twitter:site" content={metadata.twitter.site} />
        <meta name="twitter:title" content={metadata.twitter.title} />
        <meta name="twitter:description" content={metadata.twitter.description} />
        <meta name="twitter:image" content={metadata.twitter.image} />

        {/* <AuthProvider session={session}> */}
          <ThemeProvider>
            <NextProgress />
            {children}
            <Toaster />
            <GlobalDrawer />
            <GlobalModal />
          </ThemeProvider>
        {/* </AuthProvider> */}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the `metadataBase` is missing.

```
export const metadata = {
  metadataBase: new URL('https://yourdomain.com'),
  title: siteConfig.title,
  ...defaultMetadata,
};
```